# mail problems to the database

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I'm just now starting to build so that you get an email to him,
So it means approve user email before you can get inside the page.

```
if( !isset( $user_found)) {
     //sende email til brugere
     $code = rand(111111111, 999999999);
     //sendere info til brugere.
     $to = $email;
     $subject = "Activate din brugere - .....dk";
     $headers = "From: support@...dk";
     //indhold til email
     $body = "Hej";

     if(empty($errors))
     {
         if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO `brugere` (`email`, `password`) VALUES (?, ?)')) {
             /* Bind parametre */
             $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password);

             /* SÃ¦t vÃ¦rdier pÃ¥ parametrene */
                $email = $_POST["email"];
             $password = sha1($_POST["password"]);

             $stmt->execute();
             /* Luk statement */
             $stmt->close();

             echo "<div id=\"box\"><ul><li>Godkendt brugere</li></ul></div>";

         } else {
             /* Der er opstÃ¥et en fejl */
             echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklÃ¦ringen: ' . $mysqli->error;
         }
     }
 }
```

It is such that $ code must make a marginal code so that the user does something to the link after.

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST))
{              
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM `brugere` WHERE `email` = ?')) {  
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $count = $stmt->num_rows;
        $stmt->close();
         if ($count > 0)
        {
            $user_found = 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        /* Der er opstÃ¥et en fejl */
        echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklÃ¦ringen: ' . $mysqli->error;
    }
    if(!isset($user_found)) {

        //sendere info til brugere.
        $to = $email;
        $subject = "Activate din brugere - .....dk";
        $headers = "From: support@...dk";
        //indhold til email
        $body = "test";


        if(empty($errors))
        {
            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO `brugere` (`email`, `password`, `code`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)')) {
                /* Bind parametre */
                $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password, $code);

                /* SÃ¦t vÃ¦rdier pÃ¥ parametrene */
                $email = $_POST["email"];
                $password = sha1($_POST["password"]);
                $code;

                $stmt->execute();
                /* Luk statement */
                $stmt->close();

                echo "<div id=\"box\"><ul><li>Godkendt brugere</li></ul></div>";

            } else {
                /* Der er opstÃ¥et en fejl */
                echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklÃ¦ringen: ' . $mysqli->error;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "<div id=\"box\"><ul><li>Der findes allerede en bruger med denne mail</li></ul></div>";
    }
}

?>
```

That is how my code looks like,

what I want out of this is that $ code just inside its database and will be sent email to users...

**Ask if there is more to learn about it here.**

After all ask question;

```
    <?php
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

How do I do so just to use email comes into the **$to  = 'aidan@example.com'**

Comment: what ben??, i cant not show it.. ???

Comment: I think you should use a library instead. Check this out http://swiftmailer.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all it would be better if you can write the outputs in english.

send query strings in mail like

yourpage.php?user=someuserid&code=randomcode

just check in page whether user came through your provided query string or not. if he came directly send him to an error page. if he is then check for the code you created using rand function. if that exists, show the content in page.

the code may follow like this.

```
<?php
if(empty($error))
{
show_content();
}
?>
```

or what ever you can redirect the user to any page you want.

the code for checking your querystring.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['qstring'])) // qstring for query string name
{
// redirect to error page
}
else
{
$qstring = $_GET['qstring'];


//$res_code= mysql_query ()........... (result of )
//check for availability of your random code and the userid in your database table\
if(mysql_num_rows($res_code) > 0)
{
show_content();
}
else
{
//again redirect to error page or index page.
}
}
?>
```

if the code is available then show the content. you may use switch case instead of if. that depends upon you.

hope this helps for you buddy.

Comment: Sorry but I am dyslexic,

But what I want out of this is to do that you will be sent an email to the user.